# angular 6 could not undefined when creating a project

Tags: angular

I am using angular 4

I tried to create a new project in angular 6.

Using this command update angular/cli

```
npm uninstall @angular/cli
npm cache clean
npm install @angular/cli@6
```

Here is my angular version

```
 Angular CLI: 6.2.5
Node: 8.11.4
OS: win32 x64
Angular:
...

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.8.5
@angular-devkit/core         0.8.5
@angular-devkit/schematics   0.8.5
@schematics/angular          0.8.5
@schematics/update           0.8.5
rxjs                         6.2.2
```

I tried to create a new project using this command

```
ng new angular6Project
```

But i got below err.

```
Error: Could not find (undefined)
 Could not find (undefined)
```

How can i fix this issue.

Kindly advice me,

Thanks

Comment: What version of the npm do you have?

Comment: Thanks for ur comment.npm version is 6.4.1

Comment: Please try this code
npx @angular/cli@latest new angular6Project 
Let me know if this helps

Comment: npx @angular/cli@latest new angular6Project

Comment: @Drag13 No its not working.I got npm err

Comment: What error do you have?

Comment: @Drag13 I tried again project created successfully

Comment: Ok, If you don't mind I will this as an answer,

Comment: First do the backup and  Did you try removed your `node_modules dir` reinstall and then retry to run the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you have some problems with caching your packages.

The best option I can offer is to prefer using [npx](https://medium.com/@maybekatz/introducing-npx-an-npm-package-runner-55f7d4bd282b) command instead of global installation. [Npx](https://medium.com/@maybekatz/introducing-npx-an-npm-package-runner-55f7d4bd282b) is an official npm tool that solves problem with one time installations, task running and much more. So I highly recommend to give it at least a try.

So, try to use this command to start new angular project:

```
npx @angular/cli@latest new angular6Project
```

The only concern is that **you have to have npm above 5.2.0** to use it